# Sql view conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this view from 2 tables:

```
create view db1
as
SELECT
         p.pr_id
        ,p.PlotArea
        ,p.OwnershipTitle
        ,p.Price
        ,p.NotaryCosts
        ,p.AgentFee
        ,p.CtrNO
        ,isnull(p.Price,0)-isnull(a.Price,0) as Diferente
        ,isnull(p.Price,0)+isnull(p.NotaryCosts,0)+isnull(p.AgentFee,0) as TotalCosts

FROM nbProcuri p
      left JOIN nbAchizitii a
      ON p.PlotArea = a.PlotArea
where p.CtrNO=0
```

In both tables I have a column named CtrNo and one called PlotArea.

I want the view to not display records when p.PlotArea=a.PlotArea and p.CtrNo=a.CtrNo and to display all other situations.

Thanks!

Comment: you can add this conditions in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT
         p.pr_id
        ,p.PlotArea
        ,p.OwnershipTitle
        ,p.Price
        ,p.NotaryCosts
        ,p.AgentFee
        ,p.CtrNO
        ,isnull(p.Price,0)-isnull(a.Price,0) as Diferente
        ,isnull(p.Price,0)+isnull(p.NotaryCosts,0)+isnull(p.AgentFee,0) as TotalCosts

FROM nbProcuri p
      left JOIN nbAchizitii a
      ON p.PlotArea = a.PlotArea and p.CtrNo=a.CtrNo
where a.CtrNO is null and a.PlotArea is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 create view db1
 as
 SELECT
     p.pr_id
    ,p.PlotArea
    ,p.OwnershipTitle
    ,p.Price
    ,p.NotaryCosts
    ,p.AgentFee
    ,p.CtrNO
    ,isnull(p.Price,0)-isnull(a.Price,0) as Diferente
    ,isnull(p.Price,0)+isnull(p.NotaryCosts,0)+isnull(p.AgentFee,0) as TotalCosts

FROM nbProcuri p
  left JOIN nbAchizitii a
  ON p.PlotArea = a.PlotArea
  where p.PlotArea=a.PlotArea and p.CtrNo=a.CtrNo
```